# When there is two for() loop, the second one doesn't work

Tags: java

Here are my for() loops :

```
public void showMovementCase(){
    int movePlusAttack = moveAllowed+attackDistance;
    int twiceMoveAllowed = (moveAllowed)*2;
    for(int i = 0; i <= movePlusAttack*2; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j <= movePlusAttack*2;j++){
            boolean a = movePlusAttack <= j+i && movePlusAttack >= j-i && i <= movePlusAttack;
            boolean b = movePlusAttack <= j+i && movePlusAttack >= i-j && i > movePlusAttack && j <= movePlusAttack;
            boolean c = movePlusAttack*3 >= j+i && movePlusAttack >= j-i && i > movePlusAttack &&  j >= movePlusAttack;
            if(a || b || c){
                try{
                    actionSquare[i][j] = new JLabel();
                    actionSquare[i][j].setIcon(redsquare);
                    actionSquare[i][j].setBounds(sprite.getX()+(i-movePlusAttack)*16,sprite.getY()+(j-movePlusAttack)*16, 16, 16);
                    panel.add(actionSquare[i][j], new Integer(1));
                }
                catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){System.out.println("red :" + e);}
            }
        }
    }
    for(int x = 0; x <= twiceMoveAllowed; x++){
        for(int y = 0; y <= twiceMoveAllowed;y++){
            boolean a = moveAllowed <= y+x && moveAllowed >= y-x && x <= moveAllowed;
            boolean b = moveAllowed <= y+x && moveAllowed >= x-y && x > moveAllowed && y <= moveAllowed;
            boolean c = moveAllowed*3 >= y+x && moveAllowed >= y-x && x > moveAllowed &&  y >= moveAllowed;
            if(a || b || c){
                try{
                    actionSquare[x][y].setIcon(bluesquare);
                    System.out.println("Coucou !");
                    actionSquare[x][y].addMouseListener(mouse);
                    panel.repaint();
                    panel.revalidate();
                }
                catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){System.out.println("blue :" + e); }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

if `this.attackDistance` is different of 0, then the second loop doesn't work (it seems to stop at the `.setIcon()` command).

Do you know a way to fix this ?

Thanks for reading.

Edit:

with :

```
                try{
                    actionSquare[x][y].setIcon(bluesquare);
                    System.out.println("Coucou !");
[...]
                }
```

On the second loop, nothing is printed.

but with :

```
            try{
                System.out.println("Coucou !");
                actionSquare[x][y].setIcon(bluesquare);
```

[...]
                }

"Coucou !" is printed once.
That's why I said that "it seems to stop at the `.setIcon()` command" I should have said that sooner, sorry.

Comment: You'd probably have more luck finding out what's wrong if you break out the loop conditions into small functions as at the moment the code is virtually indecipherable as to its meaning, and if you remove the try/catch blocks (the exception is telling you you're doing it wrong; don't just ignore it!).

Comment: First, why are you just swallowing the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. If this is happening, typically you may have an issue.

Comment: It's very hard to tell what's going on in there.  If I were you I would break out those conditions you have in the if statement into intuitive variable names and do your condition combination before the if statement. Just to make it easier to read.

Comment: Ok, I added "System.out.println(e)" to both of the catch. I now know that no error is throw in both of the loops.

Comment: @WWilliwaw - So why have the try/catch there in the first place? Don't add tracing to wrong code; delete it!

Comment: Just in case... I always hate when a program is suddently killed, losing all your data, just for a minor error.

Comment: Try...catch and Exceptions can keep that from happening - if you use them properly.

Comment: No, you don't know that no exception is being thrown, because you are only catching one kind of exception.

Comment: Actually, I believe that if there is a exception I'm not catching, it's throwed. Just in case, I tested without the try/catch and there is no error.

Comment: What do you mean by "it seems to stop at the .setIcon() command"?  You're getting a null pointer exception, aren't you?

Comment: No. I don't get any error or exception : with or without the try/catch, the console doesn't show anything. By  "it seems to stop at the .setIcon() command" I mean that the second loop think it finished its job once it's the .setIcon() command turn. That's why my System.out.println("Coucou !") isn't show when I put it after the setIcon() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cleaned up your code for you.  Generally, when you have two sections of code that are supposed to be doing the exact same thing, but are not, then rolling them into one method can eliminate that possibility.

```
public void showMovementCase(){
    // probably want to remove anything left over from the last invocation
    panel.removeAll();
    for (JLabel[] array : actionSquare) Arrays.fill(array, null);
     
    colorSquares(moveAllowed + attackDistance, redsquare, null);
    colorSquares(moveAllowed * 2, bluesquare, mouse);
     
    for (int x = 0; x < actionSquare.length; x++)
        for (int y = 0; y < actionSquare[x].length; y++)
            if (actionSquare[x][y] != null) panel.add(actionSquare[x][y], 1);
}
 
private void colorSquares(int move, Icon color, MouseListener mouse) {
    int xMax = Math.min(2 * move, actionSquare.length);
    int yMax = Math.min(2 * move, actionSquare[0].length);
    for (int x = 0; x < xMax; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < yMax; y++) {
            if (isLegal(x, y, move)) {
                if (actionSquare[x][y] == null)
                    actionSquare[x][y] = new JLabel();
                actionSquare[x][y].setIcon(color);
                actionSquare[x][y].setBounds(
                        sprite.getX() + (x - move) * 16,
                        sprite.getY() + (y - move) * 16, 16, 16 );
                if (mouse != null) actionSquare[x][y].addMouseListener(mouse);
            }
        }
    }
}
 
private static boolean isLegal(int x, int y, int move) {
    // informative comment explaining why this mess makes sense
    if (move <= y+x && move >= y-x && x <= move) return true;
    // informative comment explaining why this mess makes sense
    if (move <= y+x && move >= x-y && x > move && y <= move) return true;
    // informative comment explaining why this mess makes sense
    if (move * 3 >= y+x && move >= y-x && x > move &&  y >= move) return true;
     
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Here are a few tips:

- don't catch exceptions and do nothing with them. That's what you are doing here in both loops, and so it's normal you don't see the error message.
- anytime you see long statements like you have, it should be a hint that you could refactor it. For example, create a separate method that validates whether or not you're going to do something in your loop, and then inside the main method you'd call it like `if(shouldPerformAction())`
- consider using less than 8 spaces for indentation. This just eats up your screen real estate.
- consider making computations before the loops instead of inside the loop conditions, if the computation is supposed to be fixed (for example `this.moveAllowed*2`)
- imho, no point in prefixing all your methods/fields with `this`, it just clutters everything. Just call the methods directly.

Answer (score 5):

This is a **very, very bad idea**:

```
catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){}
```

You effectively tell the JVM to ignore any problems with your arrays that it detects. And worse than that: you don't even print anything when that happens.

Put *at least* a `e.printStackTrace()` in there to see if a problem occurs and where.

And as a further step: fix your array access to not exceed any limits. Catching an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is a terribly bad idea. Avoid having it thrown at all!

Comment: Given the overall algorithm it looks like the intention is to ignore any cells outside the valid range.  So at most I'd recommend putting a comment "//ignore" in the exception handler.  Though a better approach is to change the algorithm to check i and j and skip the step if they're outside.

Comment: Putting an "`/ignore`" in the catch-block of an unavoidable Exception that you want to ignore is better than an empty catch-block for sure. But using an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` for flow control is very, very ugly and definitely avoidable.

Answer (score 3):

Hmmm... where to begin...

I would first suggest putting something (`System.err.println(...)`?) inside of your `catch` blocks.  Or just commenting them out entirely so you'd see the full stacktrace.  What if you're hitting an exception and just not seeing it?

Answer (score 2):

```
catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){}
```

This is a bad practice for two reasons:

1. You should never catch `RuntimeException`. It is just a very helpful indicator for errors in code logic (i.e. developer errors) which ought be solved by writing *good* code.
2. You should never ignore `e` unless you know perfectly what you're doing. Add at least an `e.printStackTrace()` so that you at least know that something failed.